# What options do I have to give time-only (i.e dependent on a call to a DB via http) dependent coloring to the words matching a regex?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, color

Say the special strings are those matching the regex `\<prefix[0-9]\+\>`, and say that an HTTP request I can do via `system` can tell me that that item is in one of three states, `Green`, `Red`, or `Blue`. Based on what the state is, I want a different coloring.

Clearly, the state can change over time, but I'm ok with options like recomputing the coloring only when the cursor is on that string, or when it comes into view, and so on.

I'm not asking for a full fledged solution, as probably some more design is needed, but currently I don't even know what building blocks would be more useful.

---

I think [syntax-highlighting](/questions/tagged/syntax-highlighting) is not related, as I want to color stuff based on some condition that varies with time and with nothing else in the buffer, so it's not a syntax-depended coloring but just a time-dependent coloring. Nonetheless I include the tag as I think experts with that tag might have something to say about it.

Comment: I think this is precisely the type of thing that `:help text-properties` were designed for. You might also be interested in `:help job`, `:help channel`, if you can arrange for a long-running daemon, instead of polling `system()`.

Comment: That said, the Q as written may not fit well in the SE Q&A model. What does a good answer look like? How do we vote? (It might be "too broad", for example, or hard to judge the answer quality.)

Comment: I agree with what has already been said. It looks like you are artificially lumping together two easy problems: a) doing things asynchronously, solved with `:help channel`, and b) programmatically highlighting arbitrary strings, solved with either `:help text-properties` or simply by `:help matchadd()`.

Comment: So, this question was bumped because of an edit but I'm afraid there is not much we can do to answer it than what has already been done. You really have two easy and separate problems, here, so you should address them separately.